# Android: how to set the height of view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been created a button and use `addView()` to draw some chart in `onClickListener()`. But it will not extend the height of view automatically if the chart out of bound.So I want to add the height of view when all chart have been drawn. I try to use `getLayoutParams().height` to modify the height but it doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     private TableLayout layout;
     private Button btnDraw;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           layout=findViewById((TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout));
           btnDraw=findViewById((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDraw));
           btnDraw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                   public void onClick(View arg0) {
                          layout.addView(new Chart(MainActivity.this)
                   }
           });
     }

     class Chart extends View {
           public void onDraw(Canvas c) {                 
                   int addHeight=0;     
                   for(...){ //draw several chart
                        ...
                        addHeight+=500;

                   }
                   FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
                   params.height += addHeight;
                   layout.setLayoutParams(params); 
           }
     }
}
```

here is xml code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDraw"
                android:layout_span="2" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Draw" />

        </TableRow>
            ...
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I also try to call `onMeasure(getWidth(),addHeight)` outside the for loop but it still not work.

```
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Chart` class should implement `onMeasure()` if you want to do it the eight way. If it is just a hack you can use [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html). You can also play with setting the layout params, but you should call `updateViewLayout()` and possibly even `requestLayout()`.